# Don't want to stop user intercation with app whether data is arrived or not from web service

Tags: android, parsing, listview

I have one app in which i called the webservice and set the data in listview after parsing.

Now I have set the progress dialog till the data set in the listview.
Now I want to go back to the previous screen whether parsing is done or not.

So overall, i don't want that user should wait in the same screen till the data arrived and set.

Hope i am clear.

Any snippets or guidelines will be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Show us what have you done so far so we can diagnose your problem easily..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a new Thread for all your work in the background .. while the UI handler (thread) do something different for the user while they wait. check out http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html .. might find it useful

Comment: i have used the thread whereever necessary in my app,but still the app performance is slow and user have to wait more to run the app.any other clue?

Comment: will intent service be helpful to me ?

Comment: then i suggest u follow the answer below by @fiddler.. after all he seems to be more experienced than myself :)

Comment: i am not saying that your answer is not valuable for me. i am totally new to android and that's why i am discussing this point to get more clear idea.. Sorry if my answer hurts you :(

Comment: haha not at all ..im new to android myself. but i noticed your question was similar to an issue i had and i fixed it with threads. dont worry about it.

Comment: ohhh dear, your answer is a big relief for me.so by using thread i am damn sure that my UI thread is not being hanged.But main issue is the performance where user have to wait so does it is being affected by parsing ? FYI, i am using DOM Parsing and data is in XML format.Also, XML does not contais huge data ......

Comment: what i did for my issue was the following: i had a thread called workerThread to request addresses and locations according to user input... while the UI thread is being controlled by a handler (handler sits between the new thread and UI thread).. to view progress dialog on the screen for the user. i found its better to keep the user wait couple of seconds than complicating your app. (if you keep them busy with a cool spinning loading screen .. they wont mind the few second wait)

Comment: nice dude.can you guide me to any links or code snippet or would you mind to share some code ?

Comment: check out this link.. thats what helped me to solve the issue http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

Comment: no worries...if my answer was helpful ..u can choose it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loading to be done independently of the lifecycle of the Activity that contains the ListView, then you probably need to implement a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

This service would be responsible for loading data from the server, store it (in the app DB for instance) and possibly notify the ListView (if it's currently visible) when loading is done.

On the other side, when your ListView is displayed you should check if data is available in DB, and display your loading spinner if it's not ready yet.

In your case, an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) may be helpful.

Comment: will intent service worked for me in all view like listview,gridview,etc.?

Comment: The Service is an entity that runs in background independently of any UI stuff. The IntentService is a special service that makes it easy to handle this kind of single-shot task like downloading data from a server

Comment: okay.so can you guide me to any tutorial or any good site which contains the snippets so i can get better idea. Also, your guidance is useful for me .Thanks dear :-)